# Эффективный контейнер для пула

Tags: python, python-3.x

Стоит задача создать пул объектов SignalRepr. Свободен ли элемент пула определяется с помощью SignalRepr.empty.
Проблема заключается в том, что в качестве контейнера пула используется список и каждый раз, при добавлении нового элемента приходится проходиться по всему списка. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, более эффективную реализацию пула.

```
import copy

class SignalRepr:

    def __init__(self):
        self.signal = list()

    @property
    def empty(self):
        return len(self.signal) == 0

    def update(self, new_signal):
        self.signal = copy.deepcopy(new_signal)

class Pool:

    def __init__(self, signal_figure, spectrum_figure):
        pool_len = 30
        self.objects = [SignalRepr()
                        for indx in range(pool_len)]

    def add_signal(self, name, new_signal):
        for signal in self.objects:
            if signal.empty:
                signal.update(name, new_signal)
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

Может как-то так? И наверное лучше не list, а deque или set. Ну и требуется чтобы набор объектов сигнал не мог быть изменен из вне.

```py
import copy

class SignalRepr:

    def __init__(self):
        self.signal = list()

    @property
    def empty(self):
        return len(self.signal) == 0

    def update(self, new_signal):
        self.signal = copy.deepcopy(new_signal)

class Pool:

    def __init__(self, signal_figure, spectrum_figure):
        pool_len = 30
        self.objects = [SignalRepr() for indx in range(pool_len)]
        self._is_empty = [x for x in range(pool_len)]

    def add_signal(self, name, new_signal):
        index = self._is_empty.pop()
        self.objects[index].update(name, new_signal)

    def remove_signal(signal):
        index = self.objects.index(signal)
        self.objects[index].update([])
        self._is_empty.append(index)
```